# How to do a PHP curl post with -d option

Tags: php, curl, post

I need to post to an application with one of the data is `xml` string. To pass the `&` and `special characters`, the application suggests to `curl post` with `-d option`.

How do pass `-d option` with `PHP curl`?

Comment: You can set all the options using http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php. But the -d option is unknown to me...

Answer (score 2):

The `-d` flag is the POST Data flag.

To send POST fields using curl via PHP do the following:

```
$ch = curl_init( $url );
# Setup request to send xml via POST.
$payload =  "xmlRequest=" . urlencode($input_xml);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload );
# Return response instead of printing.
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
# Send request.
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

You'll get your XML in the "xmlRequest" on the other side.

Comment: I am using CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to pass the xml data. The request fails if the data contains & symbol.

Comment: urlencoding works but the data is stored in the application in the encoded form. May be it is application issue.

Comment: If the answer solved that issue, mark the answer as accepted, please. The other problem is a different issue (post a different question). Regards.